# Qt: alternative to QMetaObject::invokeMethod

Tags: qt

In Qt, I often use something like `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "myMethod", Q_ARG(bool, foo))` (effectively, this causes the method call + args to be queued and later executed on the correct event queue).

Is there a way to use method references instead of using the method name as string (i.e. use `&MyClass::myMethod` instead of `"myMethod"`), while still queueing execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Qt 5.10 there are two [QMetaObject::invokeMethod](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod-4) overloads which accept functor or a pointer to a member function as an argument.

Inside the same thread you can use [QTimer::singleShot](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot-6) overload accepting functor (since Qt 5.4) and use zero milliseconds timeout.